# Testing @select decorators with @angular-redux/store

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, redux

When testing components in Angular that rely on the `@select()` decorators I am using `MockNgRedux.getSelectorStub('myStoreProperty').next(testState)` to send new values to subscribers, but when I call the next function, it doesn't trigger the subscription with the new value.

See example code:

```
export class BasicInfoComponent {
    @select() application$: Observable<Application>;
    this.application$.subscribe((app: Application) => { 
        //... this code is never triggered.
    }

}
```

Here is the test setup

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [BasicInfoComponent],
      imports: [
        NgReduxTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      providers: [
       //... providers
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BasicInfoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    MockNgRedux.reset();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call `MockNgRedux.reset()` before the component has been created. MockNgRedux connects to all `@select` decorators that get created during the tests, calling reset after a `@select` decorator has been created by the component will disconnect the `MockNgRedux` from all decorators it is currently connected to.

Modify the `beforeEach` function to look like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // NOTE: MockNgRedux Reset must happen before the creation of the component
    // otherwise it will reset the connections to the select decorators.
    MockNgRedux.reset();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BasicInfoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but it was caused because I was using lambda selection in `@select(...)`. It seems that `MockNgRedux` needs you to call `getSelectorStub` with the exact same selector as the `@select(...)` uses.

So, if you have

```
const selectorStub = MockNgRedux.getSelectorStub(['status', 'text']);
```

Then you also need to select it the same way in the component:

```
@select(['status', 'text'])
readonly statusText: Observable<string>;
```